# How to inspect HTML cache content/size on a per URL basis

Tags: caching

Is there any way to inspect the cache content (keys, value sizes in bytes)  for the HTML cache of a site? Ideally, I would like to be able to see a table with the columns

- URL/CacheKey
- Size (Bytes)

I know I can go to http://example.com/sitecore/admin/cache.aspx and see the *total size* of the HTML cache for a given site, but I would like a more fine-grained view.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was needed to look inside HTML cache and used 2 options for it:

1. I [have created special web page](http://sitecorevn.blogspot.com/2018/05/how-to-check-what-is-inside-sitecore.html) that will display cache key + cache content
2. I used Sitecore.Rocks. It allows to see cache keys out of the box. But [with small enhancement](http://sitecorevn.blogspot.com/2018/05/it-is-copy-of-my-article-placed-in.html), you can see what is inside cache.

P.S. Depending on Sitecore version code for page or Sitecore.Rocks could be different. And that is the reason why it was not approved as PR to Sitecore.Rocks.